# How can we deal with intersection tables that quickly grow very large?

Tags: database, database-design

For example, we have table A, and table B which have a many-to-many relationship. An intersection table, Table C stores A.id and B.id along with a value that represents a relationship between the two. Or as a concrete example, imagine stackexchange which has a user account, a forum, and a karma score. Or, a student, a course, and a grade. If table A and B are very large, table C can and probably will grow monstrously large very quickly(in fact lets just assume it does). How do we go about dealing with such an issue? Is there a better way to design the tables to avoid this?

Comment: Could you post a schema and a few example tuples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no magic. If some rows are connected and some aren't, this information has to be represented *somehow*, and the "relational" way of doing it is a "junction" (aka "link") table. Yes, a junction table can grow large, but fortunately databases are very capable of handling huge amounts of data.

There are good reasons for using junction table versus comma-separated list (or similar), including:

- Efficient querying (through indexing and clustering).
- Enforcement of referential integrity.

When designing a junction table, ask the following questions:

1. Do I need to query in only one direction or both?<sup>1</sup>

   - If **one direction**, just create a composite PRIMARY KEY on both foreign keys (let's call them PARENT_ID and CHILD_ID). Order matters: if you query from parent to children, PK should be: {PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID}.
   - If **both directions**, also create a composite index in the opposite order, which is {CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID} in this case.
2. Is the "extra" data small?

   - If **yes**, [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the table and [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) the extra data in the secondary index as necessary.<sup>2</sup>
   - I **no**, don't cluster the table and don't cover the extra data in the secondary index.<sup>3</sup>
3. Are there any additional tables for which the junction table acts as a parent?

   - If **yes**, consider whether adding a surrogate key might be worthwhile to keep child FKs slim. But beware that if you add a surrogate key, this will probably eliminate the opportunity for clustering.

In many cases, answers to these questions will be: **both, yes and no**, in which case your table will look similar to this (Oracle syntax below):

```
CREATE TABLE JUNCTION_TABLE (
    PARENT_ID INT,
    CHILD_ID INT,
    EXTRA_DATA VARCHAR2(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE (PARENT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CHILD_ID) REFERENCES CHILD_TABLE (CHILD_ID)
) ORGANIZATION INDEX COMPRESS;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX JUNCTION_TABLE_IE1 ON
    JUNCTION_TABLE (CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID, EXTRA_DATA) COMPRESS;
```

Considerations:

- `ORGANIZATION INDEX`: Oracle-specific syntax for what most DBMSes call clustering. Other DBMSes have their own syntax and some (MySQL/InnoDB) imply clustering and user cannot turn it off.
- `COMPRESS`: Some DBMSes support [leading-edge index compression](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/02/17/index-compression-part-i-low/). Since clustered table is essentially an index, compression can be applied to it as well.
- `JUNCTION_TABLE_IE1`, `EXTRA_DATA`: Since extra data is covered by the secondary index, DBMS can get it without touching the table when querying in the direction from child to parents. Primary key acts as a clustering key so the extra data is naturally covered when querying from a parent to the children.

Physically, you have just two B-Trees (one is the clustered table and the other is the secondary index) and no table heap at all. This translates to good querying performance (both parent-to-child and child-to-parent directions can be satisfied by a simple index range scan) and fairly small overhead when inserting/deleting rows.

Here is the equivalent MS SQL Server syntax (sans index compression):

```
CREATE TABLE JUNCTION_TABLE (
    PARENT_ID INT,
    CHILD_ID INT,
    EXTRA_DATA VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES PARENT_TABLE (PARENT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CHILD_ID) REFERENCES CHILD_TABLE (CHILD_ID)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX JUNCTION_TABLE_IE1 ON
    JUNCTION_TABLE (CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID) INCLUDE (EXTRA_DATA);
```

Note that MS SQL Server automatically clusters tables, unless PRIMARY KEY **NONCLUSTERED** is specified.

---

*<sup>1</sup> In other words, do you only need to get "children" of given "parent", or you might **also** need to get parents of given child.*

*<sup>2</sup> Covering allows the query to be satisfied from the index alone, and avoids expensive double-lookup that would otherwise be necessary when accessing data through a secondary index in the clustered table.*

*<sup>3</sup> This way, the extra data is not repeated (which would be expensive, since it's big), yet you avoid the double-lookup and replace it with (cheaper) table heap access. But, beware of [clustering factor](http://oracle-online-help.blogspot.com/2006/11/clustering-factor_28.html) that can destroy the performance of range scans in heap-based tables!*

Comment: Thank you, this was a great answer, and I appreciate the links provided for follow-up reading.